# Idioms with prepositions and CMS Capitalization

Tags: idioms, prepositions, capitalization

I am finding the CMS instructions confusing on whether one should capitalize the word *under* in a title when it is used as an idiom. For example,

> A Park under Threat.

Comment: For the benefit of the uniniatiated you should spell out what CMS stands for.

Comment: Is there any reason it would be different as part of an idiom? I've never heard of such a rule. Have you, and if so where? The rules are designed for [quick guidance](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/CapitalizationTitles.html) and don't involve deep pondering of whether something is metaphorical, idiomatic, or literal. (Obviously you may choose to deviate from Chicago if you think it looks ugly and nobody is there to stop you.)

Comment: Better to ask yourself if *under* is a minor word. It's not here.

Comment: Do you mean CMOS (*The Chicago Manual of Style*)?